# How can I pass a .csv file as a parameter for pipe.fit() method? [Python]

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, pipe, k-means

I have to read a .csv file in order to apply the K-Means algorithm on it. The steps I did are the following:

1. Reading the .csv file with the method genfromtxt() of the numpy library;
2. Creating a pipeline to apply MinMaxScaler and PCA;
3. Creating a pipeline to perform K-means;
4. Chaining these two pipelines together;
5. Invoking pipe.fit(data) to execute K-Means, where data is the data extracted from the csv file, with the method above.

But here is the problem, I get an error like:

`" Line #349907 (got 77 columns instead of 77) "`

for each of the 371750 rows of the file.
Here is the code:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import Axes3D
from sklearn.cluster import KMeans
from sklearn.decomposition import PCA
from sklearn.metrics import silhouette_score, adjusted_rand_score
from sklearn.pipeline import Pipeline
from sklearn.preprocessing import LabelEncoder, MinMaxScaler
import seaborn as sns

#Read CSV
df = pd.read_csv("C:\\Users\\giuse\\Desktop\\MaterialeTesi\\dataset\\dataset_utilizzati\\mon77.csv")
#or in alternative
df_alter = "C:\\Users\\giuse\\Desktop\\MaterialeTesi\\dataset\\dataset_utilizzati\\mon77.csv"

#Extracting data from txt
data = np.genfromtxt(
    df_alter,
    delimiter=",",
    usecols=range(1, 78),
    skip_header=1
  )


#This is a pipeline to process the data before using KMeans, because
#they are not in the optimal format otherwise
preprocessor = Pipeline(
    [
        ("scaler", MinMaxScaler()),
        ("pca", PCA(n_components=2, random_state=42)),
    ]
)

#This is a separate pipeline to perform KMeans clustering
clusterer = Pipeline(
   [
       (
           "kmeans",
           KMeans(
               n_clusters=3,
               init="k-means++",
               n_init=50,
               max_iter=500,
               random_state=42,
           ),
       ),
   ]
)

#The Pipeline class can be chained to form a larger pipeline.
#Build an end-to-end k-means clustering pipeline by passing the "preprocessor" and "clusterer" pipelines to Pipeline:
pipe = Pipeline(
    [
        ("preprocessor", preprocessor),
        ("clusterer", clusterer)
    ]
)

#The pipeline performs all the necessary steps to execute k-means clustering on the data:
pipe.fit(data)
```

As you can see I tried reading the file with the method read_csv of the pandas library, but then I have struggle using it as a parameter of pipe.fit().
In the method genfromtxt I specified with "usecols=range(1, 78)" that I want to read all the 77 columns, and with "skip_header=1" that I want to skip the first row.
Cannot find a solution in any way.

Comment: Without the file we can't help (and probably don't want to).  For now every thing your code and question except the `genfromtxt` is fluff.  For a start I'd try load the file without the columns parameter.

Comment: There is no way to attach such a file here, anyway it's a simple comma separated value file, with the first row made of labels and the ohter rows which are numeric values. It's a 371'750 rows with 77 columns. If I try executing the cose above without the column parameter I get a ` ValueError: Input X contains infinity or a value too large for dtype('float64').     `

Comment: Can `pd.read_csv` handle this file?

Comment: Yes, It can correctly read the file. The problem Is that I cannot pass It as a parameter of the pipe.fit() method (Or maybe I don't know how to do It). Anyway thanks in advance for answering me